# JanRain OpenID in PHP SREG?

Tags: php, openid, janrain, sreg

I setup the demo with a modified login I found called open-id selector. the login works fine and the identity url comes back, but the SREG data I ask for is never populated, required or optional. I am logging into my page with a gmail account. Here is the code from my try_auth.php that I edited

`$sreg_request = Auth_OpenID_SRegRequest::build(
                                     // Required
                                     array('email'),
                                     // Optional
                                     array('fullname', 'gender', 'timezone', 'dob', 'country'));`

what gives?

Comment: Where you able to get SREG from myopenid? For some reason it comes blank for me from there too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google's OpenID identity provider doesn't support SREG.

Instead, they support [OpenID Attribute Exchange](http://openid.net/specs/openid-attribute-exchange-1_0.html) for limited attributes (username and e-mail address, I think). It's newer than SREG, although I'm not sure which is more common in the wild. The Janrain library should support both though, I'd imagine.

If you want to test with an IdP that definitely does support SREG, try [MyOpenID](http://www.myopenid.com/).

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware it supported only AX and this library does support AX.