# How to distinguish/identify users with OpenID without requesting SReg fields?

Tags: php, authentication, openid, janrain

I've been toying with the JanRain OpenID PHP Library, mostly following along with [a tutorial I found on ZendZone](http://devzone.zend.com/article/3581).

How does one distinguish between users - especially Google users, who all end up using the same OpenID URL, https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id ?

Basically, I'm at the point where I can detect that they have an OpenID account... that they've successfully authenticated... but my app still doesn't know who they are; only that they authenticated.

To distinguish users, the tutorial uses a "Simple Registration request" to request the user's email of the OpenID provider - and then use email address to see if this is a returning user.

It wasn't working for me, and [apparently won't work with some providers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2459565/janrain-openid-in-php-sreg) so I was excited when I stumbled upon a function `getDisplayIdentifier`.

```
require_once "Auth/OpenID/Consumer.php";
require_once "Auth/OpenID/FileStore.php";
// create file storage area for OpenID data
$store = new Auth_OpenID_FileStore('/wtv');
$consumer = new Auth_OpenID_Consumer($store);
$oid_response = $consumer->complete("http://example.com/oir_return");
if ($oid_response->status == Auth_OpenID_SUCCESS) {
    $hopefullyUniqueUserID = $oid_response->getDisplayIdentifier(); // I assumed this would be a relatively permanent way to identify the user...
                                           // I was wrong.
}
```

Unfortunately, after a couple of hours the value returned by `getDisplayIdentifier` changes.

Comment: Please read the specification carefully. `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id` is the user supplied identifier, the user doesn't necessarily claims he owns it, its purpose may just be guiding the user to select an identifier, as is the case with Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that [Google's OpenIDs are Unique Per-Domain](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/googles-openids-are-unique-per-domain/); I had been absent mindedly alternating between `http://www.mysite.com` and `http://mysite.com`, which caused the OpenID identity url to change!

Answer (score 5):

Skimming the code, I think it's `$oid_response->identity_url` that you want. For me (albeit in DotNetOpenAuth not php-openid) that comes back as

`https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawmqjknrgk6f9cNdPIVxW43GewJPa1ZW4GE`

from Google, where the ID part is reproducible and hopefully unique to me. However I haven't left it a few hours to see if this changes, so apologies if this is what you already had from getDisplayIdentifier - but skimming the source it looks like it'd just use the first part, but then I'm no PHP expert.

Comment: That's identical to what `$oid_response->getDisplayIdentifier()` gave me... and I did leave it a few hours and it changed :'( Nonetheless, I'll try it.

Comment: I'm awarding this answer the bounty, but waiting to accept it; I don't know why `getDisplayIdentifier()` (and `identity_url`) changed on me before as it seems to not be happening anymore.

Comment: Cheers. Sorry, I don't have a good answer for that. For OpenID 2 I'm confident these are the correct values to use ( http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#positive_assertions http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-2_0.html#identifying ) and that it's called something similar in 1 ( http://openid.net/specs/openid-authentication-1_1.html#rfc.section.4.2.2.3 ). Skimming the JanRain code I had thought there was a separate 'display url' return as well, which is where I'd thought the confusion was coming from, but that's not actually in the spec after all.

Comment: Sorry Rup, but I figured out the problem, so I've unaccepted this one and accepted my own answer.

Comment: No problem - I didn't know that about Google OpenIDs, happy to learn something!

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use the OpenID URL to identify users? Consider it unique like an email address.

Comment: I thought that's how it worked too, but he says he's seeing all Google users from the same OpenID URL.

Comment: As did I, but Google accounts always have `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id
` as their URL.

Comment: stackoverflow somehow gets a `?id=....` at the end of the url. Not sure how though. Maybe the full url with the `?id=..` is given to you by google?? Does `$oid_response` have have a url attribute?

Comment: Oops, hadn't seen your last comment before I posted. Yes, I think it's the OpenID 'claimed_id' that you want, which appears to include the ?id=, which I think is `$oid_response->identity_url`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the last paragraph below, you should definitely use the `identity_url` attribute of the response object (granted, this is in reference to the Python library, but the implementations are *very* similar):

> The display identifier is related to the Claimed Identifier, but the
>   two are not always identical.  The display identifier is something the
>   user should recognize as what they entered, whereas the response's
>   claimed identifier (in the L{identity_url} attribute) may have extra
>   information for better persistence.
>
> URLs will be stripped of their fragments for display.  XRIs will
>   display the human-readable identifier (i-name) instead of the
>   persistent identifier (i-number).
>
> Use the display identifier in your user interface.  Use
>   L{identity_url} for querying your database or authorization server.

From the [python-openid docs](http://python-openid.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.2.5/classopenid_1_1consumer_1_1consumer_1_1Response_ad4916ea220e765e688d43a3c42218b90.html).